# How to navigate through google Map in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on loading the google map and navigating through the map.

I have loaded the google map which shows the current location in unity.

Now I need to show the direction from Place A to Place B.How Can I implement this in unity

Comment: To legally get data from Google Maps into your game, you need to have the written permission from Google, you know that, right?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt : No I have no permission.How can I get the permission and how to implement that into unity?

Comment: Maybe start from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/) and read a lot. Can't help you further.